# Which sources of CO2 emissions are currently considered for The European Union Emissions Trading System?

Tags: european-union, environmental-policy

[This article](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/etudes/BRIE/2020/649352/EPRS_BRI(2020)649352_EN.pdf) describes the Carbon emissions pricing used in the European Union. This is part of the European Union Emissions Trading System (ETS) which [provided good results despite low prices](https://www.pnas.org/content/117/16/8804):

> (..) the EU ETS, which **initially regulated roughly 50% of EU carbon
> emissions from mainly energy production and large industrial
> polluters**, saved more than 1 billion tons of CO2 between 2008 and
> 2016.

I am trying to find out the list of all economical sectors that are part of the ETS (e.g. [Transportation, Electricity, Agriculture](https://www.epa.gov/ghgemissions/sources-greenhouse-gas-emissions)).

**Question:** Which sources of CO2 emissions are currently considered for The European Union Emissions Trading System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EU ETS covers ...

> - power and heat generation
> - energy-intensive industry sectors including oil refineries, steel works and production of iron, aluminium, metals, cement, lime, glass,
>   ceramics, pulp, paper, cardboard, acids and bulk organic chemicals
> - commercial aviation

... although some small power plants / industrial installations are excluded, and in aviation the ETS currently only applies to flights between airports located in the European Economic Area.

[Source: European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/clima/policies/ets_en)

Examples of carbon-intensive sectors that are not included are transport, agriculture and shipping, although the idea of the ETS (tradeable allowances for stationary sources of GHG) wouldn't necessarily be applicable to all of them.